# mark a slave permanently offline in jenkins using an API

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am looking for a way to mark a slave permanently offline in jenkins through an API and i got this

```
http://[jenkins_url]:8080/computer/[slave_name]/doDisconnect?offlineMessage=bye
```

But the slave connects again when the next time a job runs on this.

Is there a way to permanently disconnect a slave so that it does not connect automatically again unless started manually?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That seems similar to [JENKINS issue 13140](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13140)

> To prevent reconnect after manual disconnect, don't configure Jenkins to `Keep this slave online as much as possible`.

Try also the Jenkins plugin "[jenkins-keep-slave-disconnected-plugin](https://github.com/daniel-beck/jenkins-keep-slave-disconnected-plugin)".

Changing my slaves to "take this slave on-line when in demand and off-line when idle", and as suggested set

```
in demand delay = 0
idle delay = 1000000
```

That does not prevents that, when a slave is required by a job, the slave process is started.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but is there a way to disable the slave forever, like the node should not start when required, it should only start when started manually

Comment: @panda Yes, I understand that: I suppose this should be managed by adding a label to the node, but I am still looking for the API call.